# Jms Connection using Apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, jbossfuse, jnp

I am trying to establish connection with JMS using Apache Camel , the server 
    is using Jnp protocol. But i am getting exceptions while trying that. Need 
    help , if i am missing anything or doing something wrong. I have the JMS API 
    jar dependency in the pom.

**Technology Stack :**

- Jboss Fuse 6.3
- Apache Camel(for Integration)

**Blueprint :**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" 
 id="remoteJndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://x.x.x.x:yyyy</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    id="remoteConnectionFactory" init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="remoteJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <!-- <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"/> -->
    <property name="expectedType" value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean factory-method="getObject"
    factory-ref="remoteConnectionFactory" id="jmsInConnectionFactory"/>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" id="jmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsInConnectionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Exception :

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean remoteConnectionFactory
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory is not visible from class loader
```

Answer (score 0):

jnp is JNDI naming service used in JBoss".
I think below test case can help you further.
[activemq-unit using spring JNDI](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/resources/spring-jndi.xml)

Regarding

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory is not visible from class loader

this looks like different issue.